# Do I have to use $u$-substitution here?

Tags: integration

In the integral

$$\int \frac{4}{\sqrt{2-x^2}}\ dx$$

Once I have

$$\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}}$$

According to online calculators, the next step is substitute $u$ for $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$. However, how is what I'm about to do incorrect?

$$\text{Let } \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} = \sin \theta$$

$$\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \cos \theta \ d\theta$$

Then, I end up getting $$\frac 4 {\sqrt 2}\arcsin (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}) + C$$

But it should only be

$$4\arcsin \left(\frac x {\sqrt 2}\right) + C$$

Where did that pesky $\sqrt 2$ drive me off course?

Comment: $dx = \sqrt{2}\cos\theta d\theta$

Comment: @Flowsnake It seems to me I need to do $x = \sqrt{2} cos\ \theta \ d\theta$ to arrive at that. Why does what I did not valid?

Comment: Please see my edits to the question for the proper user of \text{} and \sin and \cos in MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

From$$\frac x{\sqrt2}=\sin\theta,$$what follows is that$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt2}=\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta.$$